# How do you get window.open to work in internet explorer 7?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, popup, window

I've been trying for the past 3 hours to get my svg web site to open popups, and all I ever get is "Permission Denied" errors in internet explorer. I've tried everything I could find on google, and nothing works. I've even gone to the point of just calling window.open() blank with no parameters, and still get a permission denied error. What is the currently accepted standard for opening popups in internet explorer... that works?

Comment: Most browsers won't allow you to open popups programatically without the user triggering them. If these popups are not the direct result of a user click, I think you're out of luck.

Comment: This prompted another post about proper usage of the offensive designation at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459152/why-do-you-mark-a-post-offensive

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is part of the security changes made in IE6.  Now you can only call "window.open" from within a user-initiated event.  For example, your code would work inside an element's onclick event.  The ["window.open" MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651(VS.85).aspx) says this:

> "This method must use a user-initiated
>   action, such as clicking on a link or
>   tabbing to a link and pressing enter,
>   to open a pop-up window. The Pop-up
>   Blocker feature in Internet Explorer 6
>   blocks windows that are opened without
>   being initiated by the user."

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation! I guess I will just have to make it a user initiated event somehow.