# window.open does not open in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to open a word document using window.open as below

```
window.open("myworddoc.doc");
```

It works fine in FF, but IE tries to open a tab, but closes it immediately and jumps back to the current screen (no dialog is displayed to save or open a file).

What could be the issue?

Comment: FYI: Seems like a security feature in IE check ot [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459024/how-do-you-get-window-open-to-work-in-internet-explorer-7)

Comment: Browsers usually hate opening popups using `window.open` unless it was an action triggered by the user.

Comment: @Emmanuel. The discussion says that window.open should be triggered on user based action. I am using a drop down value to trigger it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is surely a security mesure. Opening Word documents using JavaScript could have nasty effects. Imagine if you are browsing the internet, and someone makes an infected Word document open when your page loads.

Personally, I'd create a PHP file, let's say "servedoc.php", and open that file like so:

```
window.open("servedoc.php");
```

servedoc.php could contain something like this:

```
<?php

$file = "myworddoc.doc"; 

header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
header("Content-Type: application/msword");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

readfile($file);
```

IE will open the PHP file, as it's a perfectly valid web file. And the PHP script would serve the file to the browser, asking the user to download the file.

Comment: Why are you sending `application/zip` as the content-type?

Comment: Oups! Copy-pasted this from a working example I had. Forgot to change the MIME type, thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

Or if you are using .net (vb):

```
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg" 'mime type of the file to serve.
Response.AddHeader("content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=YOURFILENAME")
Response.TransmitFile(YourFILEPath)
```

Like this you can let them download the .doc or the .zip file if you prefer.