# window.open is not working on IE

Tags: javascript, html

I am using following anchor tag to open a pop up. It is working fine on FF & chrome but not on IE. Please suggest.

```
<a href="javascript:void window.open('<%=script.toString()%>&noui=1&amp;jump=doclose','deliciousuiv5','location=yes,links=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,width=550,height=550');"><span class="TopBarRightSection"><s:text name="text.bookmarklet"/></span></a>
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459024/how-do-you-get-window-open-to-work-in-internet-explorer-7

Comment: What does the generated html look like?

Comment: should there be a `;` between `void` and `window.open`? or should `void` NOT be there at all?

Comment: no html is genertaed.. it show script error.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if Popup blocker is enabled in IE.