# Form popup window getting block in internet explore

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, internet-explorer

This form is suppose to go to the next and open another popup window. I'm also having it passing the form data to both pages.

The problem I'm having is the popup window is showing in all browser except IE. It keeps getting blocked by the popup blocker in IE. I need the popup to show without getting blocked.

```
<script language="javascript">

    function myChangeHandler() {

        var form = document.getElementById('TheForm');
        form.method = 'POST';
        form.action = 'https://test.com/page1';
        form.target = 'window_1';

        window.open('', 'window_1','fullscreen=1,scrollbars=1');
        this.form.submit();

        var state_ac = document.getElementById('stateDrop');
        var state_dd = state_ac.options[state_ac.selectedIndex].value;
        window.location = 'https://test.com/page2';
    }

</script>


<form id="TheForm" action="https://test.com/page2" method="post">

    <select id="stateDrop" name="state" size="1" onchange="myChangeHandler.apply(this)">
        <option value="null" selected="selected" style="color:#b3b3b3">- Select Your State -</option>
        <option value="AL" class="others">Alabama</option>
        <option value="AK" class="others">Alaska</option>
        <option value="AZ" class="others">Arizona</option>
    </select>

    <input id="featured-image-right-button" type="image" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/featured-image-right-button.png" alt="" disabled="disabled" />

</form>
```

EDIT: see the example here, the popup works in every other browser when the option is selected but the pop up is blocked in ie. It works fine in IE when the button is clicked but the popup is blocked when the option is selected http://jsfiddle.net/uyeq3/

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
Internet Explorer blocks onchange events from popups, you could do the action when the user clicks a button and that would allow the popup through the blocker.

```
<input type="button" value="Change Country" onclick="myChangeHandler();return false;"/>
```

Comment: I believe this is not the case, I went to another site that had a pop up and the pop up came up fine however when I try with my code my popup gets blocked... Do you have another suggestion as to why my code doesnt seem to function correctly?

Comment: can you give me an example of the site that allows the popup how you would like it ?

Comment: may be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459024/how-do-you-get-window-open-to-work-in-internet-explorer-7

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5Tck2/ this works on a button but I am having trouble trying to get it to work on my form, as you can see the pop up will not be blocked.