# How to bypass the pop blocker through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to open new tab through javascript but popup is blocking it .How to bypass the popup blocker .I tried this but didn't work.I tested this in chrome,Edge and firefox:

```
var interval =5000;
setTimeout(function() { 
    $("#dummyButton")[0].click();
}, interval);
```

My html code contain anchor

```
<a id="dummyButton" href="http://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank" style="display:none;"></a>
```

I even tried this:

```
<button id="dummyButton" style="display:none;"></button>

 setTimeout(function() {    
    $("#dummyButton").click();
}, interval);
$("#dummyButton").on('click',function(){
    window.open("https://facebook.com", '_blank');
});
```

I read in some post that if window.open is called from within an event then popup doesnot block.But it didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get window.open to work in internet explorer 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459024/how-do-you-get-window-open-to-work-in-internet-explorer-7)

Comment: I am not using window.open

Comment: You are trying to logically create an event that would cause a new window to open.  It's most likely hitting the same restrictions.

Comment: No nothing wrong with this if I allow popup blocker then it works.

Comment: Sounds like an "XY problem" question to me, unless you're trying to get popup ads to bypass the mechanism designed to thwart them. If you're not creating popup ads, maybe you should explain why you're trying to open a window on a delay and we can try to provide a better approach to solve your problem that doesn't _need_ to bypass a popup blocker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it were that easy to bypass the popup blocker, everybody would be doing it.

Most modern browsers only allow new windows to be created in response to a *real* click event by the user. Simulating an event using `.click()` doesn't count.